# Livewire Laravel - Every time I try to call a method, I get a div livewire-error with 404 page

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've just installed livewire/livewire and I'm trying to make my first component.

I am trying to save a variable each time the user clicks an  tag.
The component renders fine, the problem is whenever I click on it I get this in the middle of my page:

```
<div id="livewire-error" style="position: fixed; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; padding: 50px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); z-index: 200000;" tabindex="0">
<iframe style="background-color: rgb(23, 22, 26); border-radius: 5px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<!-- 404 ERROR PAGE -->
</iframe></div>
```

which shows a 404 error page.

Here is my component's blade file:

```
<div>
<li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block"><a class="nav-link nav-link-style" wire:click="switchMode"><i class="ficon" data-feather="moon"></i></a></li>
</div>
```

And here is my component's PHP file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class DarkMode extends Component
{
    public function switchMode()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        dd($user);
        if($user->darkMode == 0) $user->darkMode = 1;
        else $user->darkMode = 0;
        dd($user->id);
        $user->save;
    }
    
    public function mount() 
    {

    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.dark-mode');
    }
}
```

My version of Laravel is **8.76.2**, and my version of Livewire is **2.8.2**

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the href in your anchor tag (href="#").

```
<div>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-lg-block">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-style" wire:click.prevent="switchMode" href="#">
            <i class="ficon" data-feather="moon"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

You can use this method to toggle. (If your darkMode field is boolean)

```
public function switchMode()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->darkMode = !$user->darkMode;
    $user->save;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've actually found the problem - it was my route cache.

Comment: That's good. :)